# The type of namespace name 'Control' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, .net

Trying to set up an extension method in .Net 3.0 using generics and I get an error message, details above on the line:

```
foreach(Control childControl in parent.Controls)
```

Am I missing a using directive or assembly reference?

Thanks

What I am trying to do is set this up (below) as an extender function:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices
{
    public static class ControlHelper
    {
    public static T FindControl<T>(this Control parent, string controlName) where T : Control
    {
        T found = parent.FindControl(controlName) as T;
        if (found != null)
            return found;
        foreach (Control childControl in parent.Controls)
        {
            found = childControl.FindControl(controlName) as T;
            if (found != null)
                break;
        }
        return found;
    }
}
}
```

I am missing a reference to the system.core.dll... its driving me nuts!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Choose the one for the technology you're using:

**Windows Forms:**

It's located in `System.Windows.Forms.dll` in the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace.

**WPF:** (probably not this one, because there's no relevant `Controls` property in the WPF classes)

It's located `PresentationFramework.dll` in the `System.Windows.Controls` namespace.

**Web Controls:**

It's located `System.Web.dll` in the `System.Web.UI` namespace.

Comment: Yeah I mean just make sure you have the reference to the DLL and you've got the using directive or access it via its fully-qualified name.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I edited the question as this better explains what I am trying to do, extendor function for web control .FindControl, still getting errors and tired.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the System.web.dll to refrence in solution explorer at right side.
2. Add the namespace - System.Web.UI.WebControls; at the top of your web page.
3. then you can create the web control by the coding itself.